# Неизменямость строк в Java

Tags: java, строки

В книге П. Ноутона, Г. Шилдта  "Java 2. Наиболее полное руководство." сказано:

> Кроме того, нужно понять, что объекты типа `String` неизменяемы. Если `String`-объект создан, то его содержимое не может быть изменено. Хотя данное утверждение похоже на серьезное ограничение, однако это не так по двум причинам:
>
> ```
>   если нужно изменить строку, то всегда можно создать её новую модифицированную копию;
>
>   Java определяет класс просмотра (peer class) для String, называемый StringBuffer,  
>   который позволяет строкам стать изменяемыми, так что все нормальные манипуляции со 
>   строками все еще доступны в Java. (StringBuffer описан в Части 2 этой книги).
> ```

Я решил проверить данное утверждение и написал программу, изменяющую `String`-объект:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package teststring0;

/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
public class TestString0 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    String str="Тестовая строка 1";
    System.out.println(str);
    str="Тестовая строка 2";
    System.out.println(str);
    
    }
}
```

которая в `NetBeans` выдает следующий результат:

```
run:
Тестовая строка 1
Тестовая строка 2
ПОСТРОЕНИЕ УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНО (общее время: 0 секунд)
```

Что авторы имели ввиду под неизменяемостью `String`-объектов (видимо я неправильно понимаю авторов книги)?

Comment: http://www.skipy.ru/technics/strings.html

Comment: кароче говоря каждая строка это уникальный обьект, если вы изменяете строку значит вашей переменной подставляется ссылка на совсем другой обьект типа стринг. именно поэтому рекомендуют использовать StringBuilder, и не писать конструкций вида: "my name is: " + name + ". hello from "

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Под неизменяемостью, или иммутабельностью (immutability) подразумевается невозможность изменения содержимого объекта после его создания.

Следующий код лишь заменяет *ссылку* на объект, не модифицируя самого объекта:

```
str="Тестовая строка 2";
```

Строковый литерал из правой части выражения представляет собой заранее созданный объект.

Comment: @Flammable , разве литерал `"Тестовая строка 2"`, присваеваемый `str`, не изменяет содержимое объекта `str`?

Comment: @ivan31, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 7):

Смотрите.

В Java есть объекты, и есть ссылки на объекты. Когда вы пишете

```
String s = "hello funny world";
```

ваше `s` -- ссылка на объект-строку. Сам объект никогда не меняется. Чтобы "изменить" строку, вам придётся создать *новую* строку, и присвоить `s` ссылку на эту новую строку.

Все функции, манипулирующие строками, возвращают именно новую строку, а вы просто заменяете ссылку на старую строку ссылкой на новую.

Пример:

```
String s1 = "123";
String s2 = s1;       // обе ссылки указывают на одну и ту же строку
String s3 = "456";    // другая строка
s1 = s1.concat(s3);   // изменили ссылку, создалась новая строка, и s1 ссылается
                      // на неё
System.out.print(s1); // печатает новую строку: "123456"
System.out.print(s2); // печатает старую строку: "123", в s2 осталась
                      // старая ссылка
```

Comment: а если final String s = "hello funny world"; ?)))

Comment: @Gorets: тогда переприсвоить `s` будет, конечно, нельзя. А в чём подвох?

Comment: не какого подвоха, все правильно

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле содержимое объекта класса String можно поменять с помощью reflection, но с некоторыми ограничениями. Только делается это совсем не так, как пишете вы.

Comment: @pirj: использование reflection -- это хак, никто не гарантирует его работоспособность. Например, оптимизатор имеет право предполагать, что строки неизменяемы, и не перечитывать значение, даже если оно фактически изменилось. Хотя строго говоря вы правы.

Comment: но вроде же value, где храниться массив символов имеет модификатор final, а для  него есть кое-какие гарантии... Так что скорее всего увидит.

Comment: @VladD вы ошибаетесь. Reflection не хак, а стандартный метод для просмотра классов и объектов, и гарантированно работает в том случае, если не запрещён политикой безопасности. [Пруф](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/reflection/spec/java-reflection.doc.html). Под ограничениями я имел в виду во-первых длину строки, которую нельзя увеличить, а можно лишь использовать такую же, либо меньшую, и собственно ограничения по политике безопасности, которые по умолчанию позволяют использовать Reflection API.

Comment: @KoVadim: У `final char[]`'а никто не отменял операцию `[]=`, так что посимвольно можно поменять содержимое. Стоит иметь в виду, что это теоретически может привести к побочным эффектам на другие объекты класса String, использующие тот же объект, на который ссылается `final char[]`.

Comment: @pirj: это хак, поскольку никто не ожидает от строки возможности изменения.

Начнём хотя бы с того, что строки в старых версия Java делили свой контент. То есть если у вас были строковые константы "мама" и "мама анархия", они имели право разделять данные, и отличаться лишь индексом начала и длиной (вы наверняка знаете, как строки устроены внутри).

Допустим, вы изменили содержимое строки "мама анархия" в коде на "папа стакан портвейна". Теперь, если вы напишете в коде "мама" + s, где s было " мыла раму", то у вас получится, понятно, "папа мыла раму".

А теперь скажите, что описанное не хак.

Comment: @VladD: Как раз об этом и писал выше, говоря о побочных эффектах. Стоит всё же понять, что именно тут хак. Изменение содержания объекта класса `String` - это, естественно, хак. А вот  применение Reflection API я хаком не считаю. Использование для тех же целей `sun.misc.Unsafe` - хак. Если стоит вопрос, как поменять содержимое `String`'а, то подразумевается, что человеку нужен хак для обхода какого-то ограничения. Но выполнить этот хак можно не прибегая к более глубоким хакам, думаю, что вы понимаете о чём я.

Comment: @pirj: Для меня хак -- это то что нельзя оставлять в production-коде. Ну или можно, обкладывая трёхэтажными комментариями. Применение Reflection для _чтения_ -- скользкая вещь, так как имена приватных полей в будущем имеют право поменяться без предупреждения. Применение же его для модификации -- ящик Пандоры, приводящий к "невозможным" ошибкам и трёхэтажному мату тех, кому их придётся исправлять. В конце-концов, любую программу можно пропатчить во время выполнения, но не считать же это нормальным способом? Если ограничение нельзя обойти без хака, на мой взгляд, лучше его и не обходить.

Answer (score 2):

Дополню немного [[@Flammable](/users/10467/flammable)](/users/10467/flammable)

> Что авторы имели ввиду под
> неизменяемостью String-объектов
> (видимо я неправильно понимаю авторов
> книги)?

проверить можно способом

```
System.err.println(str.substring(0, 10)); // произвели операцию над строкой
System.err.println(str); // вывели строку, но она не изменилась
```

метод вернет новую строку, так как str - не поменяется, что будет видно, по логу

Comment: а как это будет видно по выводу prinln?

Comment: отредактировал ответ (добавил комментарии)

Comment: Не изменилась, но в коде нет намеков на ее изменение. В классе String попросту отсутствуют методы-мутаторы, поэтому ты не сможешь показать иммутабельность так, как пытаешься.

Comment: `str.substring(0, 10)` не производит действий над строкой. Он создает новый объект (который собственно и возвращается). Но вот что интересно, что этот новый объект и str будут шарить один общий массив символов и будут отличатся только полем length. Правда в 7 (или в 8) java это все поменялось и теперь создается честный новый объект с своим массивом. Почитайте на [досуге](http://www.javaspecialist.ru/2011/05/javalangstring.html), очень занимательно.

Answer (score -3):

**ИМХО , авторы имели ввиду что класс String объявлен как final** и от него нельзя унаследоваться, нельзя переписать методы. да в общем ничего нельзя. *фундаментальность java _ [хехЪ]*

[линк на исходник](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)

```
The <code>String</code> class represents character strings. All
string literals in Java programs, such as <code>"abc"</code>, are
implemented as instances of this class.
Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they
are created. String buffers support mutable strings.
Because String objects are immutable they can be shared. For example:
```

public **final class String**
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence{...}

Comment: У вас неправильное имхо.

Comment: обоснуй _)

Comment: Все верно, но об это уже все отвечающие ранее писали (правда без ссылки на **единственно достоверный источник** (т.е. source code) (+1)).

Comment: скачал , нашел, прочитал -- в самой книге разжевано написано __все, что сказано в коментариях__ выше. )